How to integrate Chatbuilder with Bitrix24 using Make (Integromat) to send leads to CRM?
I am trying to integrate Chatbuilder with Bitrix24 using Make (formerly Integromat) so that the lead data captured in Chatbuilder is automatically sent to the Bitrix24 CRM.
when I created a new scenario in Make and tried to configure it in Chatbuilder, the system prompted me to select or create a new organization, even though I am already an admin. I'm not sure how to proceed with this step.
